# Double-log density plot

Tags: r, plot, loglog

I have a generated a data set with power law distribution using `poweRlaw` package with the following code:

```
library("poweRlaw")
xmin = 1; alpha = 1.5
con_rns = rplcon(1000, xmin, alpha)
```

How can I get a log-log plot where x-axis is showing `log(m)` and y-axis showing `log(freq(m))` for all m in the dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution:

```
library("poweRlaw")
xmin = 1; alpha = 1.5
x = rplcon(1000, xmin, alpha)
h <- hist(x, plot=F, breaks=c(seq(0,max(x)+1, .1)))
plot(h$counts, log="xy", pch=20, col="blue",xlab="Value", ylab="Frequency")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the `ggplot2` package because it is easy to learn, versatile, and widely used.

```
#your code
library("poweRlaw")
xmin = 1; alpha = 1.5
con_rns = rplcon(1000, xmin, alpha)

#loading ggplot2
require(ggplot2)

#convert to data.frame format for ggplot2
df <- as.data.frame(con_rns)

#make plot with both axes log scale
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = con_rns)) + 
    geom_line(stat = 'bin', binwidth = 0.1) + 
    scale_x_log10() + 
    scale_y_log10()
```